# Separability and smoothness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, smoothness, separable-algebras

Let $A \subseteq B$ be commutative noetherian rings.
I have found the following claim: **"Separability implies smoothness"** with the following explanation:
"The natural thing is to prove that a separable algebra is a regular homomorphism (and so smooth if it is of finite type). In general ...".

Remark: I am only interested in finitely generated algebras, so did not quote the rest of the explanation.

However, it seems to me, at least with my definitions, that this claim is false:
If $A \subseteq B$ is separable, then (assuming the claim is true) $A \subseteq B$ is smooth, then by a result of Grothendieck, $A \subseteq B$ is flat, but this seems too much (especially in view of 
[Examples on pages 95-97](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-015-8555-2_5) and [Corollary 9](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869380902331/1-s2.0-0021869380902331-main.pdf?_tid=73b8ca36-2846-11e5-8b8e-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1436672055_edd3c1b73a42fb02541d5db701287e09); I do not see why separability should imply flatness of $B$ over $A$. Notice that actually, this is what the explanation suggests: it says that separability implies $A \to B$ is a regular homomorphism, and by definition, a regular homomorphism is flat).

I will really appreciate if one can either post a sketch of proof/tell me where I can find a proof, or a counterexample.

Actually, I have already posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358096/separability-implies-smoothness), but got no comments thus far.

**EDIT:**  I work with the definition of separability of [this book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540053712), and with the definition of smoothness of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(81)90217-9).

Comment: There is something confusing about the premise of this question, as follows. Separability means that the surjective map $\pi: B\otimes_A B \rightarrow B$ makes $B$ a projective $B\otimes_A B$-module, but $\pi$ is surjective, so by injectivity of flat local maps it follows that $I := \ker(\pi)$ satisfies  $I_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p} \supset I$ of $B \otimes_A B$. Hence, $\Omega^1_{B/A}=0$, so smooth $A$-algebras with positive relative dimension (e.g., $B=A[T]$!) are *never* separable. Have I misunderstood something? If not, then what is the motivation for this question?

Comment: Thanks. The motivation is a comment on MO which claims that "separablity implies smoothness"; the (beginning of the) explanation in the comment says: "The natural thing is to prove that a separable algebra is a regular homomorphism (and so smooth if it is of finite type). In general ...".

Comment: @user237522 Where is the comment "separablity implies smoothness", can you give the link and thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The comment is in: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209379/separability-of-a-simple-ring-extension. However, I feel uncomfortable to attach the link, since it involves the person who wrote that comment (and if it's not true, maybe he wishes to delete it). Anyway, I can delete the link (after getting an answer).

Comment: @user237522: I suspect that the person who made the earlier comment must have had in mind another definition of "separable algebra" or was confused, as my argument shows that the definition of separability that you are using is never satisfied for smooth algebra which is not etale.

Comment: Maybe his definition of separability is my definition of separability+flatness, and the comment meant: "separability and flatness implies smoothness", which is. if I am not wrong, Corollary 2 of http://wwwuser.gwdg.de/~subtypo3/gdz/pdf/PPN358147735_0065/PPN358147735_0065___LOG_0035.pdf (which he mentions as a reference).

Comment: @user237522: You are misreading that Corollary 2, as it involves the condition of merely finite "flat dimension", which is much much weaker than "projectivity", the latter being the definition of "separable" in the link you are giving at the end. I showed in my initial comment above that a smooth non-etale algebra is *never* separable.  So you need to identify the correct definition of "separable algebra", and make sure it is really satisfied in the smooth case (else the question posed has no motivation); otherwise this is all quite confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! As for Corollary 2, I only tried to guess what the comment talked about, so I applied Corollary 2 to show that "separable+flat implies smooth". As for your initial comment, I do not understand why it contradicts the claim "separable implies smooth", since this claim allows the existence of smooth algebras which are not separable (like $k \subseteq k[t]$); but maybe I am missing something. I agree that this is quite confusing, because we do not know what the exact definitions the comment used.

Comment: I would add a few words to the quote of the question (boldface is mine): "The natural thing is to prove that a separable algebra is a regular homomorphism (and so smooth if it is of finite type). In general pd$_{B\otimes_AB}B<∞$ for a **flat algebra** implies regularity ...". This sentence says that the easier thing to prove is not "separable implies smooth" but "separable implies regular", as it can be seen if you work with less hypothesis, such as in Theorem 1 in the paper you cite above.

Comment: As quoted, the definition of separability implies flatness. If you use a definition of "separable algebra" which does not assume flatness, take in mind that there exist non-flat local epimorphisms (see http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SAC/SAC_1967-1968__2_/SAC_1967-1968__2__A4_0/SAC_1967-1968__2__A4_0.pdf ).

Comment: Thank you very much!! Please, just to be sure, what is your definition of separability? Is it: $B$ is a projective $B \otimes_A B$-module + $B$ is flat over $A$? (if so, in the noetherian case, it's my definition of etale).

Comment: Yes, that's the definition I have in mind.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I wish to remark that the comment originally referred to a question of mine where I assumed that $B$ is free over $A$ (hence flat). The thing that remains for me to check is why a regular homomorphism implies smoothness (maybe it's easy or well-known; I have not yet tried to think about it). @Vinteuil, if you like to write this as an answer, I would happily accept it.

Comment: The usual proofs show that a regular homomorphism satisfies some kind of Jacobian criterion, and so in the case of regular homomorphisms of finite type, they are smooth (not in general if they are not of finite type, but at least we have Popescu desingularization theorem). A non-homological version of the proof can be seen in Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative, Section 7, n.10, Théorème 4. A homological one in André, Homologie des Algèbres Commutatives, Supplément, Théorème 30.

Comment: Thanks!! I will check the books you recommend. (I only know one sufficient condition for smoothness, which appears in the paper "A Jacobian criterion for smoothness" by Morris and Wang).